# Element Names in English

Tags: nomenclature, elements

Na - Sodium - Natrium

K - Potassium - Kalium

W - Tungsten - Wolfram

Sb - Antimony - Stibium

and so forth.

[English only] Why do we not use the names that match the symbols?

Comment: Because they were named in other languages first.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_of_chemical_elements

Comment: @JonCuster All the more reason the original names should be used

Comment: There was the era when English was not the major language of science. There is interesting web site http://episodictable.com with dramatised text, audio and podcasts with stories about each element. Some include also the story of their double naming.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31653/did-berzelius-unify-the-names-of-chemical-elements-using-the-latin-language

Comment: You can look at this and the links therein: https://www.loc.gov/everyday-mysteries/chemistry/item/chemical-elements/

Comment: Also if you want to learn about mercury history: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/when-was-mercury-given-its-name

Comment: Surprisingly the history of science and math SE site does not address this question particularly, although there are a few similar questions.

Comment: Anyway, I much prefer the Latin names

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited to SE History of Science and Mathematics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the $18$th and $19$th century, there was a strong rivalry between chemists of France, Germany and England, specially about giving a symbol to newly found elements. If a French chemist had discovered and given a name to a new element, the German and English had to accept it, but they often proposed another name, and another symbol, just not to obey to "the enemy". If you read old French publications from the $19$th century, you may find formula like SoCl for sodium chloride. Beryllium Be was called Glucinium Gl in France up to late in the middle of the $20$th century. This stupid rivalry was finished after WWI, in $1919$, when IUPAC was created, where delegates from the world over met just to define a unique symbol for each element. Unfortunately they failed to give a common name. But they succeeded in defining a common symbol.

Comment: Perhaps the most infamous case comes not from chemistry but from [astronomy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Georgium_Sidus).

Comment: @Maurice, Is there a reference which shows SoCl for sodium chloride? I could not find any example from Google Books. As early as 1838, NaCl was used in French works. Sodium was an English name. Why would the French embrace the symbol "So" if it ever existed.

Comment: Wikipedia reports that German chemist Ludwig Wilhelm Gilbert proposed "natronium" in 1809, the year after that element was isolated; and recorded usage of the symbol Na dates to 1814. Apart form  there is little room historically for So.

Comment: I just remember having seen once upon a time that some French chemists had used So for sodium in the 19th century. It is just a souvenir. Maybe my memory is failing.

Comment: @Maurice, I agree. I don't see any evidence of NaCl being written as SoCl. I checked early 1800s. NaCl is used there in French.

Answer (score 8):

There are several reasons for this, one of which is the pigeon-hole effect. The English language consists of only 26 letters, while nature contains more than 90 elements. The letters would become repetitive if only English names were used. Secondly, English is a latecomer as a global language of science. It is a recent phenomenon dating back to the 1900s. Early chemists were comfortable with Latin/Greek perhaps due to religious norms and education of the day. Secondly, other European languages like German and French dominated chemical knowledge and chemists had to learn at least one of them. So all these symbols were "natural" for the older generation.

Sodium and potassium were discovered by Davy, an English speaker, and he wrote "*Potassium and Sodium are the names by which I have ventured to call the two new substances*" in H. Davy, Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society 98,
32 (1807). However, "Natrium" compounds were well known in French, particularly Natron (sodium carbonate), at least two centuries earlier. What is natural then? Continue with the natural names or make up a new English symbol. What symbol can one use for sodium, S, but like the pigeon-hole effect it will overlap with sulfur, "So" is an English conjunction, perhaps it would cause more confusion. The same holds true for potassium, (Kalium and eventually from the Arabic *Kali*), its compounds were well known. German chemists had no issue with Natrium and Kalium (Na and K) because the names are still used. Wolfram is also natural to Germans, as is its symbol W, due to the fact that the mineral is well-known.

Comment: Doesn't follow. There are multiple elements with two letter abbreviations. Sodium and Sulfur could simply be distinguished by So and Su. See Chlorine and Carbon

Comment: Why do you insist that people stick to English symbols at an internationallevel? Sodium is sodium only in English. As stated earlier, English as a language of science is quite recent.

Comment: I don't. I want Latin

Comment: Natrium and Kalium are both Latin :-)

Comment: Yes, but we don't use those names

Comment: Germans do and so do many many Europeans, who is "we"? Chemistry was dominated by the German language for a very very long time.

Comment: "We" as in the title. English speaking people

Comment: And even where other languages use the English word, or maybe it is English using a word coined by the other language, the spellings may nit be the same: iodine -> Jod.

Comment: @OscarLanzi. Have you noticed that not a single element starts with J!

Comment: @Achem in English.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, Sorry, I meant officially and internationally accepted element symbol. Of course, Iodine is Jod in German and in older literature one may see J as a symbol in periodic tables.